# Installing an external ignition kill switch on a 2015 VW Golf?

Tags: ignition, alarm, ignition-switch

I'd like to install an ignition switch on a 2015 VW Golf. Something hidden, but near the front of the car .. maybe on the top of the wheel well. Nothing under the steering column or inside the car. Nothing visible when you open the fuse box.  What cables should I be looking for?

[image: fusebox]

Answer (score 1):

Why not a magnetic switch on the upper bonnet shroud below the windscreen?

Use a black thing that you just put a magnet on as you get up to the car and the magnet is easily removed as well...

For the wires just take the fuel pump relay control wire or possibly the ecu feed wire (that may confuse it though if you forget to put the magnet before turning on the ignition)...

I would hide the wires in the existing loom so it is just not obvious...

There are reed switches that will conduct with magnets - available at places like Radio Shack or Maplins or bay of fleas...